# intriguing django session save behavior

Tags: django, django-sessions

If i clear my cookies and run this view, i get a new session key each page load.

If I comment out the print, and output the session key in the template, new session key each load.

If I print session key in both view and template, the session key is 'saved' and remains the same each page load.

```
def view_session(request):
    print request.session.session_key
    return render(request, "view_session.html", {})
```

So how to explain this behavior?

It is not just two reads, as I can print twice in the view and still get new keys.

Answer (score 3):

> By default, Django only saves to the session database when the session
>   has been modified -- that is if any of its dictionary values have been
>   assigned or deleted
>
> To change this default behavior, set the SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST
>   setting to True. When set to True, Django will save the session to the
>   database on every single request.
>
> Note that the session cookie is only sent when a session has been
>   created or modified. If SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST is True, the
>   session cookie will be sent on every request.

From [when sessions are saved](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved).

Comment: thanks, but the question is really about understanding why the behavior occurs, not just how to change it.

Comment: Update your question with your view code. You are not supposed to access session properties directly, only as a dict.